# closed topological space

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $Y$ is closed in $X$. For every $A\subset Y$, if $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $Y$?

motivation: in the Munkres 'topology', there was an exercise dealing with the converse of my problem. However, I found that the converse was not that easy to solve. I have proved that if the topology is given in the metric space, then the converse always holds, but I'm curious about the general case. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

By definition $A$ is closed in $Y$, if there exists a set $B \subseteq X$ that is closed in $X$ with $A = B \cap Y.$ Choose $B = A$.

Answer (score 1):

If conversely every subset $A$ of $Y$ that is closed in $Y$ also is closed in $X$ then $Y$ must be closed in $X$.

This because $A:=Y$ is a subset of $Y$ that closed in $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$A=A\cap Y$ thus A is closed in Y.

Answer (score 0):

The condition *for every* subset A of Y is important although it is trivial. Because if the hypothesis was true only for proper subsets of Y then Y need not be closed ,as we can see in the following example.
Let X={a,b,c} and the topology be {∅,{a,b},{a},X}.
And let Y={a,c}, hence the subspace topology will be {∅,{a},Y}.
It can be seen that every proper subset that is closed in X is closed in Y but Y is not closed in X